# Is there a way to make .ignoresSafeArea() work? Simply colored, centered ZStacks are placed in wrong position

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, layout

```
struct HomeContainerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 20, height: geometry.size.height - 20)
                .background(Color.orange)
                
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 40, height: geometry.size.height - 40)
                .background(Color.gray)
                
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 60, height: geometry.size.height - 60)
                .background(Color.red)
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center))
            .background(Color.indigo)
        }
    }
}
```

[With safe area.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8t9b.png)

By simple adding .ignoresSafeArea(), the whole thing does not size to the size of the device screen?

```
struct HomeContainerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 20, height: geometry.size.height - 20)
                .background(Color.orange)
                
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 40, height: geometry.size.height - 40)
                .background(Color.gray)
                
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 60, height: geometry.size.height - 60)
                .background(Color.red)
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center))
            .background(Color.indigo)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[Ignoring safe area.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYnVa.png)

This is making it impossible for me to set up an app with SwiftUI. Is there a way to ignore the safe area and have the inner-contents size to the size of the device minus the safe area? I have spent a long time trying to de-riddle this. Thanks!

Comment: You can add background colour directly in all your `ZStack` as the first view. `ZStack { Color.orange }` instead of setting color in background.

Comment: That's a good point, @NiravD.  I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) three options to obtain the results you are looking for:

### First Option

The views are sized correctly, but the background color is drawing outside of the frame.  You can clip the background to the frame by adding `.clipped()` to each inner `ZStack`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 20, height: geometry.size.height - 20)
                .background(Color.orange)
                .clipped()  // here
                
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 40, height: geometry.size.height - 40)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .clipped()  // here
                
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 60, height: geometry.size.height - 60)
                .background(Color.red)
                .clipped()  // here
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center))
            .background(Color.indigo)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

---

[image: Running in the simulator]

---

### Second Option

Alternatively, you can apply the clipping to each background color view itself:

```
.background(Color.orange.clipped())
```

### Third Option

As @NiravD pointed out in the comments, you can remove `.background(color)` and make the color the first `View` in each of the inner `ZStack`s:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ZStack {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange
            // additional views
        }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 20, height: geometry.size.height - 20)
```